# Proper way to extract url parameters from an htmlentities() encoded url?

Tags: php, url, html-entities

I have this php file resizeImage.php which can be called like this -

```
http://<domain>/fam/resizeImage.php?&srcImg=<url encoded URL of a remote image>&width=<width>&height=<height>
```

However, a different module calls the htmlentities encoded version of this URL, in this way -

```
htmlentities(http://<domain>/fam/resizeImage.php?srcImg=<url encoded url>&width=<width>&height=<height>)
```

So, following is a sample URL that is called -

```
http://<domain>/fam/resizeImage.php?srcImg=https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2FVRY0O_3L8VH2wxJSTiKPr72PeM5uhPPFEsHzzYdxenddpTI150M0TYpljnZisQaROR0%3Dh256-rw&amp;width=640&amp;height=960
```

Now, the request is received by resizeImage.php, but I am unable to get the parameter width using $_REQUEST['width'], but I can do the following -

- get htmlentities_decode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
- explode it using `&` to get the parameter-value pairs.
- explode using `=` to get values against parameters.

So, two things -

- I was wondering if this is the proper way to extract the parameters in this scenario.
- I do not know the reason why the calling module calls the htmlentities encoded URL. Could there be a better way to suggest them?

Comment: "I do not know the reason why the calling module calls the htmlentities encoded url." — It has to be a bug in the calling module. You use htmlentities to insert a URL (or other content) into HTML. It then gets decoded by the HTML parser. If its being encoded for HTML and then treated as a plain text URL then that is a bug.

Comment: Codeigniter's `$this->uri->segment(n)` does the same. You might want to study this? https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/URI.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's internal functions to parse and decode URLs:

- [**parse_url**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) - parse URL and get the needed components
- [**html_entity_decode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) - decode html entities
- [**url_decode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) - decode URL encoded characters
- and finally [**parse_str**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) - to parse parameter string into an associative array

So here's an example code what I'm come up with ([you can try it out here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/81630b007afd19f789968161c0228239df2e6846)):

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
parse_str(urldecode(html_entity_decode($parsed['query'], ENT_HTML401)), $tmp);

var_dump($tmp);
```

...which renders your URL parameters into an associative array:

```
array(3) {
  ["srcImg"]=>
  string(109) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VRY0O_3L8VH2wxJSTiKPr72PeM5uhPPFEsHzzYdxenddpTI150M0TYpljnZisQaROR0=h256-rw"
  ["width"]=>
  string(3) "640"
  ["height"]=>
  string(3) "960"
}
```

As for the second part, I think the second module's approach is a little bit safer, since you're placing an URL in an URL's parameter. If you don't want to hassle with parsing and stripping unnessesary parts from the parameter, then encoding the whole is a simple and safe way to keep your URL's out of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, when people send html code in get parameters htmlentities on single parameters might be ok when it comes to the label, but not for the link itself - they should use urlencode for that:

```
<a href="htpp://yourdomain.tld/?param1=<?php echo urlencode('<somehtmltag>'); ?>>htpp://yourdomain.tld/?param1=<?php echo htmlentities('<somehtmltag>'); ?></a>
```